# Most (memory) efficient way to remove elements from lists that are in a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column of lists and a set with some selected words:

```
>>>df
      column1
1    ["some", "strings"]
2    ["words", "group of words"]
3    ["more", "words"]

>>>special_words
{"some", "strings", "more"}
```

The output I would like to get is

```
>>>df
      column1
1    ["some", "strings"]
2    []
3    ["more"]
```

The code I use right now is performing well in terms of speed. However, I would expect that my memory usage goes down since I remove many elements, but this is not happening and the memory usage is even higher. Can somebody either explain why this is happening or propose alternative code??

```
# How I am doing right now
df["column1"] = [[x for x in row if x in special_words] for row in df["column1"]]
```

Comment: you can try this: `df['column1'] = df['column1'].apply(lambda row: [x for x in row if x in special_words])`. but I am not sure if it is memory efficient

Comment: `memory usage` - how do you measure it?

Comment: @Poolka I am working on Jupyter Notebook, so I can run the command `!top` to see the memory consumption in terms of RAM. I just meant that it seems that doing it my way the memory that I thought Python would release due to removal of elements in lists is not happening. Therefore, my consumption on RAM seemed to be higher after the removal of the elements than before.

Comment: try the same check with `dataframe.memory_usage(deep=True)` and compare results